# LINQ: bad conversion from LINQ to sql query

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting some problem with the conversion of linq query to sql query. The source of the problem is when i am using IBPUNO field what is a string type in the edmx file and nchar in sql server)

```
var query = (from c in ContextM3.MPLINE where c.IBSUNO == supplier.M3Code.Trim() &&       orderNumbers.Contains(c.IBPUNO)
```

The conversion of the "where" clause from linq query to sql servr is something like:

```
...WHERE ([Extent1].[IBSUNO] = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@p__linq__0)))) AND ([Extent1].[IBPUNO] IN (N''177828'',N''7115912'))',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'8100033   '
```

If I execute this sql query in the ssms I got no rows but if i change the sql query to

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[IBSUNO] = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@p__linq__0)))) AND ([Extent1].[IBPUNO] IN (177828,7115912))',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'8100033   '
```

then woks fine and it retrieve the rows what i want (the change what i did is translate
the values N''177828'' TO only 177828 so my question how i can say to Net do this change??

```
[Extent1].[IBPUNO] IN (N''177828'',N''7115912'))
```

TO
    [Extent1].[IBPUNO] IN (177828,7115912))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store integers instead of strings in `orderNumbers` and convert `c.IBPUNO` to an int using `Convert.ToInt32()`:

```
var orderNumbers = new [] { 177828, 7115912 };
var query = (from c in ContextM3.MPLINE 
             where c.IBSUNO == supplier.M3Code.Trim() &&       
                   orderNumbers.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(c.IBPUNO))
             // select etc...
```

If possible you should have `IBPUNO` be an int in the first place.

Comment: yes, i follow your your answer the issue with that is that i can't change any column in the database (my query is retrieve info from a external system). BTW: i found what was the issue: the MPLINE table has values with empty strings at the begining and the end :(...

Comment: my fix was something like:
    from c in ContextM3.MPLINE
                         where c.IBSUNO.Trim() == supplier.M3Code.Trim() && orderNumbers.Contains(c.IBPUNO.Trim()

Comment: @Rolando: I'm glad to see you got it working!  If you feel that is the best answer then feel free to add and accept it.  My answer is also correct though, right?